# run job with uncommitted transaction - how to find the transaction? is it still active?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, process

By mistake I have run the job I just put into production,
but the COMMIT TRANSACTION was commented out.

when I look at the job log, it printed that it did my updates with no problem.

[image]

when I run

```
dbcc opentran
```

it says:

> No active open transactions. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed
>   error messages, contact your system administrator.

no locks or blocks are in place,
but where is my transaction?

the code for my job is here:
with the commit transaction commented out

```
--================================================================
--RUN THE UPDATE
--================================================================

BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT

BEGIN TRY

UPDATE DEStock.DBO.ItemStock 
SET     QtyOnOrder = 0 ,
        DueDate = NULL
FROM DEStock.DBO.ItemStock T
INNER JOIN TABLEBACKUPS.DBO.__RADHE R
        ON T.ITEMNO = R.ITEMNO

print cast ( @@rowcount  as varchar) + ' updating DEStock.DBO.ItemStock '


-- no updates for france
--UPDATE FRStock.DBO.ItemStock 
--SET     QtyOnOrder = 0 ,
--        DueDate = NULL
--FROM FRStock.DBO.ItemStock T
--INNER JOIN TABLEBACKUPS.DBO.__RADHE R
--        ON T.ITEMNO = R.ITEMNO

--print cast ( @@rowcount  as varchar) + ' updating FRStock.DBO.ItemStock '

-- us is on a different schedule
--UPDATE USStock.DBO.ItemStock 
--SET     QtyOnOrder = 0 ,
--        DueDate = NULL
--FROM USStock.DBO.ItemStock T
--INNER JOIN TABLEBACKUPS.DBO.__RADHE R
--        ON T.ITEMNO = R.ITEMNO

--print cast ( @@rowcount  as varchar) + ' updating USStock.DBO.ItemStock '

UPDATE EUStock.DBO.ItemStock 
SET     QtyOnOrder = 0 ,
        DueDate = NULL
FROM EUStock.DBO.ItemStock T
INNER JOIN TABLEBACKUPS.DBO.__RADHE R
        ON T.ITEMNO = R.ITEMNO

print cast ( @@rowcount  as varchar) + ' updating EUStock.DBO.ItemStock '   

--COMMIT TRANSACTION T1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH
```

the table used in the join comes from here:

[how to insert a list of varchar values, into a single column table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116178/how-to-insert-a-list-of-varchar-values-into-a-single-column-table/116181?noredirect=1#comment211176_116181)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-committed transactions will be automatically rolled-back if the session is terminated.

You can easily test this by:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTran
(
    ID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TestTran
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
);

BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTran DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTran;
```

Results will show a row inserted into `dbo.TestTran`.

Now, disconnect and reconnect the session.

```
--disconnect and reconnect

USE tempdb;

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTran;
```

The results from the above `SELECT` statement will return no results since the non-committed transaction was automatically rolled back when the session was disconnected.

This is a primary tenet of all ACID-compliant database management systems.

> Atomicity
>
> A transaction is a unit of work in which a series of operations occur between the BEGIN TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION statements of an application. A transaction executes exactly once and is atomic — all the work is done or none of it is.

Once you disconnect the session (or it completes without a `COMMIT TRAN`), the transaction will rollback to ensure none of the work has been done since the `BEGIN TRAN` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Uncommitted transactions are held open until the *connection* is terminated, and then they are rolled-back. So in connection-pooling scenarios, they will he held open longer since the connection has not terminated.

For a SQL Agent job, it might not be using connection pooling, so the distinction between Session and Connection might not be obvious.